# How to make the escape for variable whose value is already a string?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Create a `sample.csv` for the discussion.

```
cat > sample.csv <<EOF
class;grade
tom:class(3+2);80
tom:class(2+2);90
marry:class(3+2);85
marry:class(2+2);70
EOF
```

Show the data in `sample.csv`.

```
cat  sample.csv
class;grade
tom:class(3+2);80
tom:class(2+2);90
marry:class(3+2);85
marry:class(2+2);70
```

Let's read it with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv',sep=';')
df
              class  grade
0    tom:class(3+2)     80
1    tom:class(2+2)     90
2  marry:class(3+2)     85
3  marry:class(2+2)     70
```

Now i want to select all such records whose field `class` contains string  `class(3+2)` as below:

```
    tom:class(3+2)     80
  marry:class(3+2)     85
```

Get it this way:

```
classname = 'class\(3\+2\)'
df[df['class'].str.contains(pat=classname]
              class  grade
0    tom:class(3+2)     80
2  marry:class(3+2)     85
```

The difficult thing is that `classname` is already assigned value as `class(3+2)`,

```
classname='class(3+2)'
df[df['class'].str.contains(pat=classname)]
```

The above code can't work now,how to make the escape for variable `classname` whose value is already a string `class(3+2)` ?
Note:you can't write `classname = 'class\(3\+2\)'` ,its value is `classname='class(3+2)'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn `regex` to False

```
classname='class(3+2)' # this is regex () , we need turn it off just match the string
df[df['class'].str.contains(pat=classname, regex=False)]  
Out[166]: 
              class  grade
0    tom:class(3+2)     80
2  marry:class(3+2)     85
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using regex for the search, you need to escape the `+` as well, and use a raw string, like so:

`classname = r'class\(3\+2\)'`